# Rendering of <h:commandbutton> in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, jsf

When we set `disabled` attribute for  is set as true, in Firefox the button still looks like it is enabled but in IE it is working fine. Is it a limitation with Firefox or JSF.

Answer (score 1):

All JSF does is generating HTML/CSS/JS. Webbrowsers doesn't retrieve/understand JSF code at all. Style and look'n'feel is usually controlled using CSS. All you could do is to view the generated HTML/CSS/JS code for pointers related to the style of a disabled button. You could maybe create a plain vanilla HTML page to do some quick tests to exclude the one and other.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="submit" disabled>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can select a disabled submit button using the attribute selector `[name=value]` in CSS like so:

```
input[type=submit][disabled] {
    background: pink;
}
```

Test it like follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>input[type=submit][disabled] { background: pink; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="submit" disabled>
    </body>
</html>
```

And apply the learnt things in JSF side.

Comment: as you said i tried the same, i installed firebug for mozilla. when i saw the attribute list there was no disabled attribute found in the firebug. But where as in IE developer toolbar of IE ,i could find that disabled attribute.